# Поиск по бд не работает

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, поиск

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label13.Visible)
        label13.Visible = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox9.Text))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Cars] WHERE [Number] LIKE '%' ", sqlConnection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", textBox9.Text);

        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        label13.Visible = true;
        label13.Text = "Поле номеру має бути заповнене!";
    }
```

Comment: Укажите, какую именно СУБД используете.

Comment: mdf из visualstudio

Answer (score 1):

Замените `command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` на `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` и все станет хорошо :)

на всякий случай https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.6.php

Comment: А что такое `ExecSQL`?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо - поправил, очень плохо когда одновременно приходится писать на нескольких языках

Comment: проблема в том когда я нажимаю на кнопку у меня не происходит поиск

Comment: "...проблема в том когда я нажимаю на кнопку у меня не происходит поиск..." - Нужно анализировать, что получено 'reader'. Если он пустой, то ничего не нашли, если есть автомобили с нужным номером, то число возвращенных строк буде > 0. У Вас в Вашем исходном коде отсутствует анализ полученного результата. Гляньте на ссылку, что я Вам дал. Если не сможете сделать сами, то я Вам помогу, но когда у меня появится окно.

Comment: у меня выход данных должен реализоватся через windows form. я делаю через tabcontrol + listbox я сделал свою базу из этого видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh6rn1CAgis

Comment: Как-то не вяжется видео с рекламой разработки сайтов, с таблицей `Cars` ну совсем.